# Is there a way to share a template/markup with the JSON API so that it doesn't need to be declared both in PHP and in JS?

Tags: templates, page-template, json

**Current Setup**
I'm using WP's JSON API on a custom post type archive to query some posts. I then parse the returned JSON object to output my markup accordingly. I also have a single post type template for when JSON isn't available (JS turned off etc.) Currently this means I'm declaring my markup in two places;once in the JS function that renders the JSON output, and again in the single post template.

**What I'd to Achieve**
While the above approach works, I'd like to find a way to declare the markup in one location only; this will make maintenance and alterations easier easier, and **avoid me having to put markup into my JS.** I've read [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39239/sharing-templates-with-the-json-api) and had a look at `wp_localize_script` but I gather that let's you pass PHP *variables,* not the actual PHP itself. I had thought I could write all the markup *as* an array, but that seems a tad cumbersome, and seems at odds with keeping the concept of templating in general. Is there a smarter way of doing this? Perhaps some way of programatically reading the markup and turning it into an array?

**Update** I may have found an answer using `get_template_part()` and Handlebars.js, so if there are no other good answers I may post and then accept it.

Comment: I don't know if I follow 100% what you're trying to accomplish. But let's say the response has only values (no formatting). You could then create/clone the output based on an existing one - and replace the old values with the new values.

Comment: That thought had crossed my mind as well, but struck me as rather long-winded (the logic of looping over the existing markup and having to insert values seemed like a head-ache waiting to happen). Thanks for the suggestion though.